# Check In System by input user data in Django

Tags: python, django

I trying to do a check In System where Students can do it themselves by inputting their ID's but I am really struggling.

Follow views, models, forms, and html

**VIEW**

```
class Attendance(CreateView):
    template_name = 'homepage.html'
    model = GetAttendance
    fields = ['aluno']
    success_msg = "Check In Succesfully"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        success_msg = self.get_success_message(form.cleaned_data)
        if success_msg:
            messages.success(self.request, success_msg)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('attendance:homepage')

    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return self.success_msg % cleaned_data
```

**MODELS**

```
class Aluno(models.Model):

    id = ShortUUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, alphabet="0123456789", length=5)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/', default='static/images/defaultuser.jpeg', blank=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    location = models.ForeignKey(MasterUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    belt = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=BELT)
    stripe = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=GRAU)
    join_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    last_graduation = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=GENDER)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class GetAttendance(models.Model):

    aluno = models.ForeignKey(Aluno, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attendance = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.aluno) + ' - ' + str(self.attendance)
```

[That's views.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBDwJ.png)

[My models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO6cN.png)

[forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPp3i.png)

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWBKo.png)

[check in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzUya.png)

Basically what I need is instead of having the form of a choice be able to input the student ID and run the model GetAttendance.

Comment: First you have to create a form that controls the `id` you want selected. You can do this with a choice field in your model form or a text box or a integer field. All of this is simple to look up in Djangos docs. On a side note it seems strange your ID for `aluno` is a UUID. I would change this to the default primary key Django provides which would be an integer or nowadays, BigInteger

Comment: Hei @rmaleki! Actually my ID is a UUID because I want them to have 5 digits instead begins with 1, 2, 3 .... and I don't know other way to have it done.
And about the other issue, that's exactly what I don't want to .. I already have a choice field and I want it to be a INPUT field instead.
If you have a look at the screen shot 'checkinpage' You will understand better. Thank You for your help anyway!